# How can I fill pixels in canvas with a picture instead of color?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to use canvas to remove background of pictures and I am filling it with a color as such :

```
const onResults = (results) => {
    contextRef.current.save();
    contextRef.current.clearRect(
      0,
      0,
      canvasRef.current.width,
      canvasRef.current.height
    );
    contextRef.current.drawImage(
      results.segmentationMask,
      0,
      0,
      canvasRef.current.width,
      canvasRef.current.height
    );
    // Only overwrite existing pixels.
    contextRef.current.globalCompositeOperation = "source-out";
    contextRef.current.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
    contextRef.current.fillRect(
      0,
      0,
      canvasRef.current.width,
      canvasRef.current.height
    );

    // Only overwrite missing pixels.
    contextRef.current.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
    contextRef.current.drawImage(
      results.image,
      0,
      0,
      canvasRef.current.width,
      canvasRef.current.height
    );

    contextRef.current.restore();
  };
```

[image]

As it can be seen, the background is in green and the person is in front. How can I change the green color with an other picture, for example a jungle using my current code structure?

Comment: In your code, you are probably able to determine what makes the green background. Searching the web it must not be so complex to find how to *draw* an *Image* (hint, we try to make methods with obvious names when designing APIs). Have you tried replacing the former with the latter?

Comment: @Hypothesis - can you provide the actual two images (`results.image` ; `results.segmentationMask`) you're using?